# Change Image width Ajax, browser memory leaks

Tags: image, internet-explorer, firefox, memory, memory-leaks

This is my html test page:

```html
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    <style type="text/css">
        #imager img{
            width: 1050px;
            height:650px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var index = 0;
        var max = 1;

        //! get next image
        function getImage(){
            if (index  >= max ) index = 0;
            var objTest = {
                "index" : index++
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "prova.php",
                data: objTest,
                success: function(response){
                    max = response.max;
                    imageToLoad = response.imageToLoad;
                    //! Clean div
                    $("#imager").html("");
                    //! Display new image
                    $("#imager").append("<img src='"+imageToLoad+"'></img>");

                },
                dataType: "json"
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
   <body>
    <button onclick="getImage()">get img</button>
    <div id="imager"></div>
</body>
```

And this is my prova.php test page:

```php
$max = 0;
$imgToLoad = null;

// Open image dir
if ($handle = opendir('img')) {

  while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if($entry == '.' || $entry == '..' ) continue;

    if($_POST['index'] == $max)
        // Save next image to show
        $imgToLoad =$entry;

    // Image counter
    $max++;
  }
  closedir($handle);
}

$array = array(
 "max" => $max,
 "imageToLoad" => "http://192.168.1.96/prove/cache/img/".$imgToLoad
);
// Return next image and max number of image the we can show
echo json_encode($array);
```

The problem is that every time that i call "getImage()" the memory browser incrase ( IE and Firefox tested).
My 'img' folder contains a lot of very huge images, about 4600x3000px (400kb), and after a little time the memory brower is about 1 gb and so on.

Thanks for help